# Hive : How to execute a query from a file and dump the output in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I can execute a query from a sql file and store the output in a local file using

```
hive -f /home/Prashasti/test.sql > /home/Prashasti/output.csv
```

Also, I can store the output of a hive query in hdfs using :

```
insert overwrite directory 'user/output' select * from folders;
```

Is there any way I can run the query from a sql file and store the output in hdfs too?

Comment: May i know the use case behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the sql file and add the `insert overwrite directory 'user/output'` to the front of the query.